# Need help to run an existing EpiServer 6 website in my local environment

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-mirroring-2.0

I have got an existing Episerver 6 project from client and for some modification i have to run this in my local development machine.I have successfully complied the project but when I am running the project I am getting the error
Page 27 was not found and in my configuration I have set the pagestartid as '27'. What I suspect that I have only bring the code files for the project and not copy the databases with data in my local development data.I have created a Episerver site and used the database of that site to run my project.Is it the reason I am getting this error?Please help.

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes. I would recommend to get a database dump from the client as well. If you are not able to do that, then set the startpageid to 1 and you can probably get in to the EPiServer interface and add some dummy content. But it can be a hassle to get everything right depending on the solution.

So again, try to get a database dump of the live site.

Comment: Yes, client DB would help lot more, but there is also option to install empty database. Just open EPiServer Deployment Center and in All Actions tab select Install SQL Server database. After that configure connectionString properly to newly created DB and set start page ID to 1 (which is Root page ID). Login to EPiServer interface and create startpage from your project page types and then change startpage ID to your start page ID. After that you can start adding content.

Comment: @Erik Nordin I have set the pagestart id to 1 and also tried for 3 also now I am getting error in this section of the code PropertyCriteria criteria = new PropertyCriteria();  criteria.Value = PageType.Load("Klinikstartsida").ID.ToString();

Comment: @marisks in the above comment I have specified an error .Please give me some idea to overcome the situation.

Comment: Code suggests that you need to add a Page type with the name Klinikstartsida.

Comment: @Utpal This is the reason you want a database dump as well. The code is probably heavily dependent on some basic data. Especially if the site does not use Page Type Builder, because then you have to recreate all page types and page properties by hand. When you have done that, you have to figure out the structure of the site... If you cannot get access to a database dump, at least try to get a "export data" file from the live site. It could be enough, but it can sometimes be a problem to export/import a lot of data through those files.